# How to determine which software uses which WPAD proxy

Tags: windows, windows-10, proxy, wpad

I currently have a problem where I no longer know what to do: We use a WPAD script to determine the correct proxy. This is located on the server http://wpad.XXXXX.intranet/wpad.dat. However, we have noticed in the logs that there are three computers that (possibly permanently, possibly only from time to time) want to access a WPAD script at http://wpad.business/wpad.dat. But this is not defined anywhere, and I can't find anything about it in the known places of the Windows settings.

Do you have any idea how I can check what exactly this WPAD calls?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have put in place some domain-wide mechanism for
specifying the
[Web Proxy Auto-Discovery (WPAD) Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Auto-Discovery_Protocol),
but just three computers in the domain don't use it.

You should examine these computers and how they are set up :
Which browser is used, how is it configured for Auto-Discovery etc.
It's possible that in the past these computers were manually configured
differently than all others, which you will need to undo.

The WPAD standard itself defines two alternative methods for publishing
the location of the proxy configuration file: DHCP or DNS, but your
company might have created a third solution (which?).